# MySQL - How to parse string value inside of INSERT to find a sub-string

Tags: mysql, parsing, email, insert, substring

I'm getting a string value back from an external application that is supposed to be providing an email address. However, this string value sometimes is providing a display name that goes along with the email address. I only need the email address, which is inside the <brackets>, so I think I need to do some sort of sub-string or `SELECT` clause, inside of my `INSERT` statement.

Here is what my `INSERT` statement looks like, along with the test data:

```
INSERT INTO tblInquiry
(fldInquiryFromEmail)
VALUES ('"\'Tim Lastname\'" <timm@testCCaddcompany.com>')
```

Comment: you want to extract the email and store without `<`. is it so?

Comment: Whilst this *can* be done using MySQL's string manipulation functions, you'd probably fare better by doing it in your application prior to attempting the `INSERT` (that way you could use more advanced techniques like regex pattern matching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @eggyal's comment. But if you must, here's how:

```
INSERT INTO tblInquiry (fldInquiryFromEmail)
VALUES (substring_index(substring_index('"\'Tim Lastname\'" <timm@testCCaddcompany.com>', '<', -1), '>', 1))
```

Note that this still works even if you pass in a real email (without angle brackets)

Comment: Hello all. I should have mentioned that I can't change the app that is providing the string, as it is a 3rd party application. However, the example above worked perfectly. Thank You.

Comment: Sure, but you're using some program that is your own to feed the data you're receiving from the external app into MySQL, no? At the very least, the script you're generating based on the values you receive from the app is that program. So Ideally you should pre-process the data there before you stick it into MySQL. Pentaho Data Integration (aka Kettle) is great a great open source tool to do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the email from string BEFORE actual insertion in database, because it is easier.
If you're not sure which part of the space-separated string is the e-mail address, you can split the string by spaces and use PHP function `filter_var()` on every substring.

```
    //first, sanitize user input
    $str = filter_var($_POST['some_input'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //second, convert the string into array
    $str = explode(' ',$str);

    //third, check for valid email inside the array
    foreach ($str as $key=>$value) {         
      if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      echo $value;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this rather assume that the OP is using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question,  you want to extract the email address between `<>` so you can use mysql functions

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('<test@gmail.com>',2,LENGTH('<test@gmail.com>')-1)
//return test@gmail.com
```

References:

[`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

[`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

Comment: I thought the question was not just how to strip `<>` (if present), but rather how also to strip any leading recipient name (which could itself contain `<>` characters)?